# Dihedral Calculation.

Tags: geometry

I wish to turn a hollow open ended cone from wood, 6 to 7 mm wall thickness. The outside base diameter of the cone will be 220 mm, the top 165 mm.  To do this I intend to glue 6 pieces of 25 mm thick wood, about 115/120 mm long together to form a six sided cone, then turn to shape on my lathe. How do I calculate the dihedral angle ?
I need to then glue it to a cylinder of 220 mm outside diameter by 150 mm long, which is easily made by gluing 6 pieces of 25 mm thick wood together, each cut at 30 degrees.
I am retired, mathematics is not my strong point, and the task is part of a "Man Shed" type team project. Any help in trying to calculate the angles of the saw blade would be greatly appreciated. regards, Ciaran McCarthy. Ireland.

Comment: Can you provide a sketch of what you need and your proposal for getting there?

Comment: I don't understand if you want to make a cone frustum, or a pyramid frustum with hexagonal base. Some kind of (even rough) sketch would be of help.

Answer (score 0):

The dihedral $\gamma$ is simply

$$ = 2(90^0- \frac{360^0}{6\cdot 2}) \cos \alpha$$

where $$ \tan \alpha= \frac{110}{165}$$

A simple cardboard model of the hexagonal pyramid could be made at first to measure $\gamma$.